# Preventing a response if there is no cookie c#

Tags: c#, web-services, cookies

I have web service with web method:

```
namespace Temp
{
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
  public class Init : System.Web.Services.WebService
   {
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string GetData(string userCode)
    {
     // code here
    }
  }
}
```

I want to prevent from request without cookie that contain "session-id" to get response (or send respone 40x).

The request from my system has been sent with cookie like:
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=

If I make a request to this web method and remove the session-id from the cookie, I get the data from the server.

How can I prevent this situation?

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this

```
var sessionCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
if(sessionCookie == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sessionCookie.Value)
    return null; // or throw WebFaultException(httpStatusCode)
```

Comment: But what if I have 50 web method?! There's nothing more general I can do?

Comment: you can put the same snippet in the constructor of the service class. (needs to be parameterless without having to do additional work)